# Updating SQL database from a dropdown using PHP script

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am just self-learning PHP and SQL. This question seems repetitive, but I cannot find exact solution for my problem.

I have a SQL database for inventory management of mobile phones. I have implemented PHP script to display the database contents in a table. I have to further enhance the script, so the user can change the status of the mobile phone such as **Working** or **Not working**. For this I have created another SQL database storing this info. I am able to display the details in a dropdown, but when I change from **Working** to **Not working** and select **Submit** button, no change is seen in the database and also in the web server.

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="XXXXX";
$dbname="inventory_db";

//Connection

$conn =mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password);
$db_handle = $conn->select_db($dbname);

//Connection check
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed:" .$conn->connect_error);
}
else {
    echo "connection setup";
}

if($db_handle)
{
$sql="SELECT asset_no,asset_name,current_holder,location,status FROM Phone_table ";
$sql_status="SELECT idstatus,status_name FROM status_table";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <STYLE>

            .asset_table
            {
                width: 100%;
            border :1px solid black;
            }

            td{
                text-align: left;
                padding: 15px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            th{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form method="post">

<TABLE class="asset_table">
      <TR>
        <TH>Asset Number</TH>
        <TH>Asset Name</TH>
        <TH>Asset Holder</TH>
        <TH>Location</TH>
        <TH>Status</TH>
      </TR>
    <?php
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {?>
    <TR>

            <TD> <?php echo $row['asset_no']; ?> </TD>
            <TD>  <?php echo $row['asset_name']; ?></TD>
            <TD>  <?php echo $row['current_holder']; ?></TD>
            <TD>  <?php echo $row['location']; ?></TD>
            <TD><select>
                <?php
<!-- *****This is where I am stuck*****-->     
                $result_status=$conn->query($sql_status);
                if($result_status->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    while($row_status=$result_status->fetch_assoc())
                    { ?>
                        <option value =' <?php echo $row_status['idstatus']?> '> 
                       <?php echo $row_status['status_name'];?> </option>
                       <?php $row['status']=$row_status['status_name'];
                       }} ?></select>
               </TD>
    </TR>
    <?php
    }}?>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if($submit)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $sql="UPDATE Phone_table SET status='$status[$i]' WHERE asset_no='$asset_no[$i]'";
            $result=$conn->query($sql);
        }
    }
    ?>

</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
<?php }
ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: your html is invalid - there is no closing form tag

Comment: There is a closing form tag just before the end of table

Comment: oh yes... I see it now. It is, however, in the wrong place - you need to open and close elements in mirror order rather than just when it feels right ;-) glad I was able to help btw - it is easy to extend that to allow updating of all fields ( asset name,holder,location etc )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the existing code is that there was no way to relate the submitted value for the asset status ( even if it had been given a name! ) to the particular record in the database. The update statement would require, usually, an ID in the `where` clause so that the releveant record can be updated as opposed to ALL records being updated equally. To that end, given the HTML structure and generaly approach ( no javascript & single form ) using a hidden input field for each row in the table to hold the record ID seems to make sense. When the form is submitted the value for the `select` menu and the id should be relatable - you will see by the demo below.

Because there is a single form with multiple records the `select` menu and the `hidden` input will need to be treatable as arrays - that is to say their names should be of the form `name[]`

Another thing to note perhaps is the use of variables directly within the sql. This practise leaves your code vulnerable to sql injection and whilst this may be on a closed system somewhere with trusted users etc you never know what might happen!

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );


    /* connect to the db */
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'inventory_db';
    $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


    /* declare the sql statements for later use */
    $sql=(object)array(
        'phones'    =>  'select `asset_no`, `asset_name`, `current_holder`, `location`, `status` from `phone_table`',
        'status'    =>  'select `idstatus`, `status_name` from `status_table`',
        'update'    =>  'update `phone_table` set `status`=? where asset_no=?'
    );



    /* very basic utility function to generate select menu */
    function createselect( $name, $data, $value ){
        $html=array();
        $html[]=sprintf( '<select name="%s">', $name );
        foreach( $data as $id => $status ){
            $selected = $id == $value ? ' selected=true' : '';
            $html[]=sprintf('<option value="%s"%s>%s', $id, $selected, $status );
        }
        $html[]='</select>';
        return implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
    }



    /* query database to get possible status values which are used to create the SELECT menus */
    $status=array();
    $results=$db->query( $sql->status );
    if( $results ){
        while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() )$status[ $rs->idstatus ]=$rs->status_name;
    }




    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        /* using `user supplied data` - use a prepared statement to be safe! */
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql->update );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'ii', $assetstatus, $assetid );

        /* Perform the update */
        foreach( $_POST['id'] as $i => $assetid ){
            $assetstatus = $_POST['status'][ $i ];
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        $stmt->close();
        exit( header( 'Location: ?db=updated' ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Asses or Assets?</title>
        <style>
            body{font-family:verdana}
            table{ width: 100%; border :1px solid black; }
            td{ text-align: left; padding: 15px;  border: 1px solid black;text-align:center; }
            th{ border: 1px solid black; }
            input,select{padding:1rem;width:100%}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        /* get the phones... no user input so no need for prepared statement */
        $results = $db->query( $sql->phones );
        if( $results ){

    ?>
        <form method='post'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Asset Number</th>
                        <th>Asset Name</th>
                        <th>Asset Holder</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    while( $rs = $results->fetch_object() ){
                        printf(
                            "<tr>
                                <td>%s<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='%d' /></td>
                                <td>%s</td>
                                <td>%s</td>
                                <td>%s</td>
                                <td>%s</td>
                            </tr>",
                            $rs->asset_no,
                            $rs->asset_no,
                            $rs->asset_name,
                            $rs->current_holder,
                            $rs->location,
                            createselect( 'status[]', $status, $rs->status )
                        );
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=5>
                            <input type='submit' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php

        }//close `if`

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the form creation/display and the acting upon the submitted form are two entirely unrelated HTTP requests.

You have to change a few things to get your script to work:

**1. Add a hidden field for each asset no.:**

```
<TD>
<input type="hidden" name="asset_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['asset_no']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['asset_no']; ?>
</TD>
```

**2. Add name attribute to your select fields:**

```
<TD><select name="asset_status[]">
```

**3. Make your select fields preselect the current status and remove the whitespace in the value:**

```
<option value ='<?php echo $row_status['idstatus'] ?>' <?= $row['status'] == $row_status['idstatus'] ? ' selected' : '' ?>>
```

**4. Remove this statement, as it does nothing (you're not writing to the array you read from the database):**

```
$row['status']=$row_status['status_name'];
```

**5. Add a name property to your submit field:**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

**6. Read your submitted form from the superglobal array `$_POST` (see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)):**

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['asset_no']);$i++)
        {
            $asset_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['asset_status'][$i]);
            $asset_no     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['asset_no'][$i]);
            $sql = "UPDATE Phone_table SET status='$asset_status' WHERE asset_no='$asset_no'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes as mentioned, but the problem continues still